# Why were booleans created?

Tags: boolean

When I first started programming, the language I started with did not have booleans (Or, maybe they did, and I just didn't know about them) Nonetheless, I just used an integer set to either 0 or 1, for false or true. This worked out just fine for me.

So my question is, is there some specific reason booleans were created?

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR:** The more **types** and **static type safety** you put into a programming language, the harder it gets to create misunderstandings (potential bugs) between you and the compiler that make it into the executable program, undetected. A dedicated Boolean data type is an obvious and important type to add to a programming language, since logical truth values appear everywhere (`if`, `==`, `!=`, `<`, `>`, `&&`, `||`, etc.).

---

In a language like C that does not have a dedicated data type for logical truth values (aka Booleans), or does not clearly distinguish between it and the type for integral numbers:

```
0 == (1 == 2)  ?  "succeed"  :  "fail"
```

What is the result of this test?

- If it is comparing the three numbers `0`, `1`, and `2` for equality, then it should `"fail"`, because they are obviously not equal. Or,
- If it is comparing the two numbers `1` and `2` for equality, and then whether that first test failed / was false (`0`), then it should `"succeed"`.

This kind of ambiguity can easily surface in programming languages that don't provide much **static type safety**. It can lead to programming mistakes (aka bugs), not because the programming language's translator doesn't know what to do with it, but because you and the compiler might have differing ideas of what it means. Even if *you* know exactly how the test should be interpreted according to the language's rules, someone else who takes over maintenance of your code might be less well-informed, misunderstand your code, and change it (i.e. make it wrong).

**Static type systems** are supposed to prevent such ambiguities, and therefore reduce the potential for bugs right from the start. Each expression is assigned a specific static type (`3` has type `int`, `3.141` has type `double`, `3 + 141` has type `int`, `3 == 141` has type `bool`, and so on), and its static type dictates how you may combine that expression with other expressions.

For example, the C# programming language (which is fairly strongly statically typed and has a dedicated `bool` data type) enforces the following type rules:

- Integer literals such as `0`, `1`, or `2` have type `int`.
- The expression `a == b` always has type `bool` (no matter what types the subexpressions `a` and `b` have).
- Neither the type `int` nor the type `bool` define an operator `==` that allows comparing an `int` expression with a `bool` expression.

These three rules lead the compiler to reject the expression `0 == (1 == 2)` as invalid, so you cannot create an executable program from it, and a potential bug has been prevented before it could have an effect.